# Definition of Left Translation of a function on a topological group

Tags: harmonic-analysis

In Folland's *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis*, he defines for a function $f$ on a topological group $G$, and $y\in G$,

$$L_{y}f:x\to f(y^{-1}x)\text{ and }R_{y}f:x\to f(xy)$$

He then remarks that the $y$ is inverted so that the map $y\mapsto L_{y}$ is a group homomorphism.

But it seems to me that $L_{yx}f = f((yx)^{-1}\cdot) = f(x^{-1}y^{-1}\cdot) = \left[L_{x}\circ L_{y}\right]f$, making the map an anti-homomorphism.

Am I misunderstanding the remark?

Comment: Your last equality isn't right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $z \in G$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left( L_{yx}f \right)(z) &= f((yx)^{-1}z) \\
&= f(x^{-1} y^{-1} z) \\
&= \left( L_x f \right)(y^{-1}z) \\
&= \left( L_y L_x f \right)(z).
\end{align}
$$
So,
$$
L_{yx} f = L_y L_x f
$$
for
all $f \in G^*$.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know what I was thinking here.

Comment: What is $G^*$? Is it the space of all mapping from $G$ to $G$?

Comment: There are several similar but distinct notions of dual group $G^*$, depending on context. But, in every case $G^*$ is the space of functions $G \to R$, where $R$ is a fixed algebraic object, sometimes the circle group $T$ of unit modulus complex numbers, sometimes the field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Notice that the calculation is agnostic to *what* $R$ actually is.

Comment: @SammyBlack All right, thank you. Folland defines $L_y$ in his book "Real Analysis" as well, and I had some trouble understanding the notation "$L_{yx}f = L_yL_xf$", but I think I got it now.